# Find number of times a property has a truthy value in a nested object

Tags: javascript, object-oriented, lodash.js

I have a nested object and I would like to calculate the number of times the property 'error'. I am able to go n levels deep and find the count. Is there a better solution than mine?

```js
const data = {
  "item1": {
    "value": 88,
    "error": false
  },
  "item2": {
    "value": 651,
    "error": false
  },
  "item3": false,
  "item4": [],
  "item5": "",
  "item6": "",
  "item7": false,
  "item8": {
    "error": true
  },
  "item9": {
    "value": [],
    "error": true
  },
  "item10": {
    "value": [],
    "error": true
  },
  "item11": {
    "value": [],
    "error": true
  },
  "item12": false,
  "item13": {
    "subItem1": {
      "name": "Country",
      "groups": {},
      "instances": [],
      "error": true
    },
    "subItem2": {
      "name": "Group",
      "groups": {},
      "instances": [],
      "error": true
    },
    "subItem3": {
      "name": "Product",
      "groups": {},
      "instances": [],
      "error": true
    }
  }
}

function traverseAndFlatten(currentNode, target, flattenedKey) {
  for (var key in currentNode) {
    if (currentNode.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var newKey;
      if (flattenedKey === undefined) {
        newKey = key;
      } else {
        newKey = flattenedKey + '.' + key;
      }

      var value = currentNode[key];
      if (typeof value === "object") {
        traverseAndFlatten(value, target, newKey);
      } else {
        target[newKey] = value;
      }
    }
  }
}

function flatten(obj) {
  var flattenedObject = {};
  traverseAndFlatten(obj, flattenedObject);
  return flattenedObject;
}

var flattened = flatten(data);

const keys = _.keys(flattened);

const errorCount = _.map(keys, key => {
  let count = 0;
  if (key.includes('.error') && flattened[key]) {
    count++
  }
  return count
})

console.log(_.sumBy(errorCount))
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Given that the code uses lodash, when you state “_I am open to use lodash as well._” did you actually mean that you are open to _not using_ lodash?

Comment: I am open to using lodash. I will fix the OP

Comment: Are you also open to vanilla JS i.e. without lodash?

Comment: Sure. I am open..

Comment: @SᴀᴍOnᴇᴌᴀ Any luck?

Comment: please clarify what qualifies as "better" - fewer lines of code? faster? uses less memory?

Comment: Yeah, just in terms of performance and less lines of code.

Comment: Maybe not the best idea, but could be easiest to implement: `count = 0; JSON.stringify(data, function (x, y) { if (x === 'error' && y) count++; return y; }); alert(count);`

Answer (score 1):

The comment recommending `JSON.stringify` is a bit faster, but it is in the range of <1 microsecond

```js
const data = {
  "item1": {
    "value": 88,
    "error": false
  },
  "item2": {
    "value": 651,
    "error": false
  },
  "item3": false,
  "item4": [],
  "item5": "",
  "item6": "",
  "item7": false,
  "item8": {
    "error": true
  },
  "item9": {
    "value": [],
    "error": true
  },
  "item10": {
    "value": [],
    "error": true
  },
  "item11": {
    "value": [],
    "error": true
  },
  "item12": false,
  "item13": {
    "subItem1": {
      "name": "Country",
      "groups": {},
      "instances": [],
      "error": true
    },
    "subItem2": {
      "name": "Group",
      "groups": {},
      "instances": [],
      "error": true
    },
    "subItem3": {
      "name": "Product",
      "groups": {},
      "instances": [],
      "error": true
    }
  }
}

function traverseAndFlatten(currentNode, target, flattenedKey) {
  for (var key in currentNode) {
    if (currentNode.hasOwnProperty(key)) {
      var newKey;
      if (flattenedKey === undefined) {
        newKey = key;
      } else {
        newKey = flattenedKey + '.' + key;
      }

      var value = currentNode[key];
      if (typeof value === "object") {
        traverseAndFlatten(value, target, newKey);
      } else {
        target[newKey] = value;
      }
    }
  }
}

function flatten(obj) {
  var flattenedObject = {};
  traverseAndFlatten(obj, flattenedObject);
  return flattenedObject;
}
let startTime = performance.now()
var flattened = flatten(data);

const keys = _.keys(flattened);

const errorCount = _.map(keys, key => {
  let count = 0;
  if (key.includes('.error') && flattened[key]) {
    count++
  }
  return count
})

let count =_.sumBy(errorCount)
let endTime = performance.now()
console.log(count)
console.log(`Call to count error took ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds`)

startTime = performance.now()
count = 0;
JSON.stringify(data, function (x, y) { if (x === 'error' && y) count++; return y; });
endTime=performance.now()
console.log(count)
console.log(`Call to count error 2 took ${endTime - startTime} milliseconds`)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.20/lodash.min.js"></script>
```